# ARC enabled App will run in lower version of ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, automatic-ref-counting

I have developed an application using xcode 4.3.2 with ARC enabled ,my app users having  ios3.2, ios4.0,ios5.0 devices how can I give support to lower version ios device uses .Should I need to do anything in code side . or Is there any way set ARC dynamically like.

Any have any idea regarding this plz share with me.
        Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) is not device- or OS-dependent (see note below). It is a LLVM compiler feature (which can be disabled using the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag). The compiler manages the memory instead of the programmer. The final executables will not be very different from one another and will work on the minimum OS specified for your project (if you are not using ARC-specific keywords, etc.).

Note:
According to Apple's [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), ARC-compiled executables will only run on iOS 4 and above. In addition, weak references are only supported on iOS 5.

Comment: Actually, it does introduce an OS dependency if you use the @autoreleasepool keyword, as it's implementation relies on runtime functions not present pre-ARC.

Comment: but some of my user report me in lower version ios device app is crashing is this happening due to ARC enabled , r u sure this crashing   is not for ARC

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan According to Apple "@autoreleasepool even works in non-ARC code." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Yes, but not *pre*-ARC code, i.e. code running on an OS that doesn't have ARC support.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the target deployment to the lowest iOS version your users might be on.. AutoMatic Reference Counts only while compiling the app in Xcode. The memory of app enabled ARC is managed by compiler (Xcode). So you need not to worry about the target iOS version of the device. Just set the Target Deployment to 3.2 or 4 etc.

Comment: but according to apple documentation it will support from ios4.0 and latest version what does actually it mean https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226

Comment: Try setting Deployment target to 3.2 in xcode and see what happens. This is a fact that ARC remains in compiler domain, and compiler does all the memory management, so if the compiled code is already managed in terms of memory, then it should support former versions of iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think at least it is not guaranteed to work correctly on iOS 3.x. See [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.